# Highcharts : Put data labels legend inside columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to move the datalabels inside the columns.
In the example below, I would like to have October just below the "20" text in column.

How can I do that ?

Here is a working fsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cfu6fe5e/

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointPadding: 0.01,
                groupPadding: 0,
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        colors: [
           '#ffffff'
        ],
        credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    enabled: false
                }    
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
                gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        series: [{
                showInLegend: false,
            name: 'Ordered subscriptions',
            data: [
                ['October', 20],
                ['November', 19],
                ['December', 10]
            ],
            dataLabels: {
                    inside: true,
                enabled: true,
                color: '#376fbb',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign:'bottom',
                y: 20,
                style: {
                    width:100, 
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Formatter and useHTML

```
dataLabels: {
            inside: true,
            enabled: true,
            color: '#376fbb',
            verticalAlign:'bottom',
            formatter: function() {
                return  '<span style="width:20px;padding-left:15px">' + this.y + '</span><br/> <span style="width:20px;">' +this.point.name + '</span>';
            },
            y: 10,
            useHTML:true,
            align: 'center',
            style: {
                fontSize: '15px',
                fontFamily: 'Avenir'
            }
        }
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4jfbLouq/

Comment: Thanks @Deep , how can i adapt your working code to have a breakpoint to put the month below the value ?

Comment: I tried to add <br /> but the two texts are not well centered ;

Comment: Ok, let me try and come back to you

Comment: Great, i was also going to suggesting styles on element http://jsfiddle.net/5d7ep5xe/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
        align: 'left',
            x: 0,
            y: -2
        ,
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
```